# Outputting w different classes & Constructors

Tags: java, arrays, file, class, constructor

UPDATE: it was an issue that the file I was gathering text from had lol.

Whenever I try running the output, there are multiple exceptions in everything past the welcome message that prevent any output past it. Help?

Here's the shown exceptions:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.InputMismatchException
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:939)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1594)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2258)
at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2212)
at TheCupcakeFactory.main(TheCupcakeFactory.java:35)
```

Here's my main method & Class known as TheCupcakeFactory

```
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

        public class TheCupcakeFactory 
        {
            private static Scanner inputFile;
            /*
             *Diego Molina Salinas
             *CS160 Fall 2023
             *Project 4: The Cupcake Factory Sales
             *
             */
            public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
            {
                Cupcake cupcakeCS = new Cupcake();
                Cupcake cupcakeAP = new Cupcake();
                Cupcake cupcakeBF = new Cupcake();
                Cupcake cupcakeBS = new Cupcake();
                Cupcake cupcakeBW = new Cupcake();
                
                Cupcake [] cupcakes = {cupcakeCS, cupcakeAP, cupcakeBF, cupcakeBS, cupcakeBW};
                System.out.println("Welcome to the Cupcake Factory Sales Registry!!");
//          
                
                    FileReader file = new FileReader("FreshCupcakes.txt");
                    inputFile = new Scanner(file);

                    
                    //This is setting the Chocolate Strawberry Cupcake
                    cupcakeCS.setFlavor(inputFile.next());
                    cupcakeCS.setDescription("Moist chocolate cake filled with strawberry jam, topped with strawberry buttercream dipped in chocolate.");
                    cupcakeCS.setUnitsOnHand(inputFile.nextInt());
                    cupcakeCS.setPrice(2.75);
                    //This is setting the Apple Pie Cupcake
                    cupcakeAP.setFlavor(inputFile.next());
                    cupcakeAP.setDescription("Moist vanilla cake filled with apple pie filling; topped with cream cheese icing, apple pie filling, and cinnamon streusel");
                    cupcakeAP.setUnitsOnHand(inputFile.nextInt());
                    cupcakeAP.setPrice(3.25);
                    //This is setting the Butterfinger Cupcake
                    cupcakeBF.setFlavor(inputFile.next());
                    cupcakeBF.setDescription("Moist chocolate cake filled and topped with our peanut butter icing and Butterfinger candy.");
                    cupcakeBF.setUnitsOnHand(inputFile.nextInt());
                    cupcakeBF.setPrice(2.95);
                    //This is setting the Banana Split Cupcake
                    cupcakeBS.setFlavor(inputFile.next());
                    cupcakeBS.setDescription("Moist chocolate cake filled with banana filling, topped with our vanilla buttercream with sprinkles, cherry and chocolate drizzle on top.");
                    cupcakeBS.setUnitsOnHand(inputFile.nextInt());
                    cupcakeBS.setPrice(3.15);
                    //This is setting the Black & White Cupcake
                    cupcakeBW.setFlavor(inputFile.next());
                    cupcakeBW.setDescription("  Moist vanilla cupcake, topped with our rich fudge icing");
                    cupcakeBW.setUnitsOnHand(inputFile.nextInt());
                    cupcakeBW.setPrice(3.50);
                    for (Cupcake cupcake : cupcakes) {
                        System.out.println(cupcake);
                    }

            }
```

And here's my Cupcake class that has all the constructors:

```
public class Cupcake 
{
String flavor;
String description;
int unitsOnHand;
double price;

public Cupcake() {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.flavor = "";
    this.description = "";
    this.unitsOnHand = 0;
    this.price = 0.0;
    
}
public String getFlavor() {
    return flavor;
}
public void setFlavor(String flavor) {
    this.flavor = flavor;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
public int getUnitsOnHand() {
    return unitsOnHand;
}
public void setUnitsOnHand(int unitsOnHand) {
    this.unitsOnHand = unitsOnHand;
}
public double getPrice() {
    return price;
}
public void setPrice(double price) {
    this.price = price;
}
public void newUnitsOnHand(int quantity) {
    unitsOnHand = unitsOnHand - quantity;
}
@Override
public String toString() {
     return flavor + ": \t\t $" + price + " - " + description;
}

}
```

And finally, Here's the file from which I'm setting the cupcakes info on. (The numbers signify the amount of cupcakes available):

```
Chocolate Strawberry 25
Apple Pie 15
Butterfinger 25
Banana Split 30
Black & White 50
```

Comment: Please [edit] the exceptions (including stacktrace!) into the question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one problem.  The default `Scanner` delimiter is white space. Your second input for

```
Chocolate Strawberry 25
```

is `Strawberry` but it is trying to be parsed as an `int`. You need to have a consistent input format so you can properly parse the numerics.

```
cupcakeCS.setFlavor(inputFile.next());
cupcakeCS.setDescription("Moist chocolate cake filled with strawberry jam, topped with strawberry buttercream dipped in chocolate.");
cupcakeCS.setUnitsOnHand(inputFile.nextInt());
cupcakeCS.setPrice(2.75);
```

Perhaps the easiest decision is to set a specific delimiter using the `Scanner.useDelimiter()` method.  Say the delimiter is `;` your input could look like this.

```
Chocolate Strawberry ;25;
```

Notice the `;` must be right before and after the number or the space will cause an exception.

Comment: You have to add `;` even after the number

Comment: @PatrickCumpa Yep.  Fixed it. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's time we update the JWZism. The new version is: "You have a problem and decide to use Scanner. You now have 2 problems". Whomever wrote Scanner is somehow responsible for ~10% of all new `java` questions on StackOverflow. Good grief. For what its worth, this job can be done as is by foregoing Scanner entirely, looking for the last space. Or, gasp, a regular expression.

Comment: *`Or gasp, a regular expression`*.  Full circle to the JWZism.  Besides, I was trying to keep this as close to the OP's code as possible.

Answer (score -2):

Just for fun I cooked this up.

- It is line-based and uses `///` as separator.
- It uses 2 config files, no item config in the code.
- Cupcake 'prototypes' and their actual 'on hand' stock size are matched by the Cupcake's name (flavor).
- Throws a lot of Warnings when config files seem off (and yes, I put some mistakes in there on purpose).
- Calculates in cents, to get rid of common currency problems.
- App still crashes on NumberFormatException from the both input files. Just thought of that after posting all code here, so I'll let you fix that :-P

The Shop

```
package stackoverflow.cupcakemania;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.logic.CupcakePrototype;
import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.logic.CupcakeStock;
import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.util.CupcakePrototypeManager;
import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.util.StockTransaction;

public class CupcakeShop {



    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        printCurrentStock();

        takeOut();

        putIn();

        printCurrentStock();
    }



    static private void printCurrentStock() throws IOException {
        final TreeMap<CupcakePrototype, Long> stock = CupcakeStock.getStock_sorted();
        System.out.println("Current stock:");
        for (final Entry<CupcakePrototype, Long> e : stock.entrySet()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + e.getValue() + "\t" + e.getKey());
        }
    }

    static private void takeOut() {
        final CupcakePrototype cpp = CupcakePrototypeManager.getPrototypeByName("Apple Pie Cupcake");
        final StockTransaction transaction = CupcakeStock.changeStock(cpp, -3);
        System.out.println("Take out transaction:\t" + transaction);
    }

    static private void putIn() {
        final CupcakePrototype cpp = CupcakePrototypeManager.getPrototypeByName("Black & White Cupcake");
        final StockTransaction transaction = CupcakeStock.changeStock(cpp, +20);
        System.out.println("Put in transaction:\t" + transaction);
    }



}
```

The Cupcake

```
package stackoverflow.cupcakemania.logic;

import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.util.CurrencyFormatter;

public class CupcakePrototype implements Comparable<CupcakePrototype> {



    public final String name;
    public final String description;
    public final long   priceCents;

    public CupcakePrototype(final String pName, final String pDescription, final long pPriceCents) {
        name = pName;
        description = pDescription;
        priceCents = pPriceCents;
    }



    // you CAN write getters here, but you don't have to

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }



    /*
     * Those 2 methods are auto-generated but strongly recommended
     */
    @Override public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((description == null) ? 0 : description.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
    @Override public boolean equals(final Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) return true;
        if (obj == null) return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) return false;
        final CupcakePrototype other = (CupcakePrototype) obj;
        if (description == null) {
            if (other.description != null) return false;
        } else if (!description.equals(other.description)) return false;
        return true;
    }



    /**
     * This is for alphabetical sorting, not case sensitive
     */
    @Override public int compareTo(final CupcakePrototype pO) {
        if (name == null) return -1;
        if (pO.name == null) return 1;
        return name.toLowerCase().compareTo(pO.name.toLowerCase());
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return name + " (" + CurrencyFormatter.format(priceCents) + ")";
    }



}
```

The Shop's Stock

```
package stackoverflow.cupcakemania.logic;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;

import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.util.CupcakePrototypeManager;
import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.util.StockTransaction;

public class CupcakeStock {



    static private Path getFile() {
        return Paths.get("CupcakeStock.txt");
    }

    /*
     * File format:
     *
     * name1 /// amount1
     * name2 /// amount2
     * ...
     */



    static private HashMap<CupcakePrototype, Long> sStock;

    static private void loadStock() throws IOException {
        // load prototypes to match against stock
        final Map<String, CupcakePrototype> prototypesMap = CupcakePrototypeManager.getAllPrototypes_copy();

        // load stock
        final Path file = getFile();
        final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file);
        final HashMap<CupcakePrototype, Long> newStock = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            final String line = lines.get(i);
            if (line == null || line.trim().length() < 1) continue; // skip invalid and empty lines

            final String[] parts = line.split("///");
            if (parts == null || parts.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid entry in file [" + file + "], line " + (i + 1) + ": Invalid amount of config parts: [" + line + "]");
                continue; // again, skip invalid entries
            }

            final String name = parts[0].trim();
            final long amount = Long.parseLong(parts[1].trim());

            final CupcakePrototype matchingPrototype = prototypesMap.get(name);
            if (matchingPrototype == null) { // no prototype found
                System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid entry in file [" + file + "], line " + (i + 1) + ": Prototype [" + name + "] not found!");
                continue; // again, skip invalid entries
            }

            // check if ccp was already registered
            if (newStock.get(matchingPrototype) != null) {
                System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid entry in file [" + file + "], line " + (i + 1) + ": Prototype [" + name + "] already registered, ignoring entry, please fix your file!");
                continue; // again, skip invalid entries

            }

            newStock.put(matchingPrototype, Long.valueOf(amount));
        }

        // check if all Prototypes were assigned a price
        for (final CupcakePrototype ccp : prototypesMap.values()) {
            final Long value = newStock.get(ccp);
            if (value == null) System.out.println("WARNING: Prototype [" + ccp.name + "] is not in stock, please refill!");
        }

        sStock = newStock;
    }



    static public Map<CupcakePrototype, Long> getStock_copy() throws IOException {
        if (sStock == null) loadStock();
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(sStock);
    }
    static public TreeMap<CupcakePrototype, Long> getStock_sorted() throws IOException {
        if (sStock == null) loadStock();
        return new TreeMap<>(sStock);
    }
    static public Long getStockOf(final CupcakePrototype pCCP) {
        return sStock.get(pCCP);
    }

    /**
     * Adds or retrieves as many items as possible. Negative amount means take out items
     * @return null if no transaction took place
     */
    static public synchronized StockTransaction changeStock(final CupcakePrototype pCCP, final int pAmount) {
        if (pAmount == 0) return null;

        if (pAmount < 0) { // take out
            final Long stock = sStock.get(pCCP);
            if (stock == null || stock.longValue() < 1) return null;

            final long maxTransferableAmount = Math.min(-pAmount, stock.longValue());
            final long costsCents = maxTransferableAmount * pCCP.priceCents;
            final long newStockAmount = stock.longValue() - maxTransferableAmount;
            sStock.put(pCCP, Long.valueOf(newStockAmount));
            return new StockTransaction(pCCP, maxTransferableAmount, costsCents);

        } else { // put in
            final Long stock = sStock.get(pCCP);
            if (stock == null) { // did not exist before, register new value
                sStock.put(pCCP, Long.valueOf(pAmount));
            } else { // existed before, overwrite old value
                sStock.put(pCCP, Long.valueOf(pAmount + stock.longValue()));
            }
            return new StockTransaction(pCCP, pAmount, -pAmount * pCCP.priceCents);
        }
    }



}
```

The cupcake Manager

```
package stackoverflow.cupcakemania.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.logic.CupcakePrototype;

public class CupcakePrototypeManager {



    static private Path getFile() {
        return Paths.get("CupcakePrototypes.txt");
    }

    /*
     * File format:
     *
     * name1 /// price1 /// flavor1 /// description1
     * name2 /// price2 /// flavor2 /// description2
     * ...
     */


    static private HashMap<String, CupcakePrototype> sPrototypes = null;

    static private void loadAllPrototypes() throws IOException {
        final HashMap<String, CupcakePrototype> newMap = new HashMap<>();

        final Path file = getFile();
        final List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(file);
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
            final String line = lines.get(i);
            if (line == null || line.trim().length() < 1) continue; // skip invalid and empty lines

            final String[] parts = line.split("///");
            if (parts == null || parts.length != 3) {
                System.out.println("WARNING: Invalid entry in file [" + file + "], line " + (i + 1) + ": Invalid amount of config parts: [" + line + "]");
                continue; // again, skip invalid entries
            }

            final String name = parts[0].trim();
            final long priceCents = Long.parseLong(parts[1].trim());
            final String description = parts[2].trim();
            final CupcakePrototype p = new CupcakePrototype(name, description, priceCents);
            newMap.put(name, p);
        }

        sPrototypes = newMap;
    }



    static public Map<String, CupcakePrototype> getAllPrototypes_copy() throws IOException {
        if (sPrototypes == null) loadAllPrototypes();
        return Collections.unmodifiableMap(sPrototypes);
    }
    static public CupcakePrototype getPrototypeByName(final String pName) {
        return sPrototypes.get(pName);
    }



}
```

Utility method

```
package stackoverflow.cupcakemania.util;

public class CurrencyFormatter {



    static public String format(final long pCents) {
        final long dollars = pCents / 100;
        final long cents = pCents % 100;
        final String dollarsString = dollars == 0 ? "" : (dollars + "$ ");
        final String centsString = cents == 0 ? "" : (cents + "¢ ");
        return (dollarsString + centsString).trim();
    }



}
```

Shop transaction

```
package stackoverflow.cupcakemania.util;

import stackoverflow.cupcakemania.logic.CupcakePrototype;

public class StockTransaction {

    public final CupcakePrototype   prototype;
    public final long               amountOfItemsActuallyChanged;
    public final long               generatedCostsCents;

    public StockTransaction(final CupcakePrototype pPrototype, final long pAmountOfItemsActuallyChanged, final long pGeneratedCostsCents) {
        prototype = pPrototype;
        amountOfItemsActuallyChanged = pAmountOfItemsActuallyChanged;
        generatedCostsCents = pGeneratedCostsCents;
    }

    @Override public String toString() {
        return amountOfItemsActuallyChanged + "x " + prototype.name + " (=" + CurrencyFormatter.format(generatedCostsCents) + ")";
    }

}
```

CupcakePrototypes.txt

```
Chocolate Strawberry Cupcake /// 275 /// Moist chocolate cake filled with strawberry jam, topped with strawberry buttercream dipped in chocolate.
Apple Pie Cupcake /// 325 /// Moist vanilla cake filled with apple pie filling; topped with cream cheese icing, apple pie filling, and cinnamon streusel .
Butterfinger Cupcake /// 295 /// Moist chocolate cake filled and topped with our peanut butter icing and Butterfinger candy.
Banana Split Cupcake /// 315 /// Moist chocolate cake filled with banana filling, topped with our vanilla buttercream with sprinkles, cherry and chocolate drizzle on top.
invalid /// entry
Black & White Cupcake /// 350 /// Moist vanilla cupcake, topped with our rich fudge icing.
```

CupcakeStock.txt

```
Chocolate Strawberry Cupcake /// 1
Apple Pie Cupcake /// 2
Butterfinger Cupcake /// 3
Banana Split Cupcake /// 4
Banana Split Cupcake /// 667
Unknown Cupcake /// 6
```

And the app's output:

```
WARNING: Invalid entry in file [CupcakePrototypes.txt], line 5: Invalid amount of config parts: [invalid /// entry]
WARNING: Invalid entry in file [CupcakeStock.txt], line 5: Prototype [Banana Split Cupcake] already registered, ignoring entry, please fix your file!
WARNING: Invalid entry in file [CupcakeStock.txt], line 6: Prototype [Unknown Cupcake] not found!
WARNING: Prototype [Black & White Cupcake] is not in stock, please refill!
Current stock:
    2   Apple Pie Cupcake (3$ 25¢)
    4   Banana Split Cupcake (3$ 15¢)
    3   Butterfinger Cupcake (2$ 95¢)
    1   Chocolate Strawberry Cupcake (2$ 75¢)
Take out transaction:   2x Apple Pie Cupcake (=6$ 50¢)
Put in transaction: 20x Black & White Cupcake (=-70$)
Current stock:
    0   Apple Pie Cupcake (3$ 25¢)
    4   Banana Split Cupcake (3$ 15¢)
    20  Black & White Cupcake (3$ 50¢)
    3   Butterfinger Cupcake (2$ 95¢)
    1   Chocolate Strawberry Cupcake (2$ 75¢)
```